# Deploy Non-Web-Server on Heroku without domain?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

So I have a small project which I would like to deploy on heroku. It consists of one node web server, which (judging from heroku tutorials) I assume I can just start by

```
web node client/web_server.js
```

but this being a peer-to-peer application for real time data, I also have a signalling server based on websockets. with what parameters do I start it?

```
??? node signalling/sock_server.js
```

Also when using heroku, when I look up the IP of the signalling server, can I reference it directly by that address/port (as a non-web server it does not need a domain), or will the IP be dynamic and change over time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the ??? in your Procfile you can put whatever you want this process type to be called.
A common choice is "worker".

The IP will be dynamic, by default. However there are various [Heroku add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/search/addons?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Static%20IP) you can consider using if you need to route outbound traffic through static IP addresses.